# Maximum update depth exceeded - React Js

Tags: reactjs

This error :
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

why is this error?

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
       constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state=({
           todos:[],
         })
         this.add = this.add.bind(this);
         this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    }
    //this.array.splice(2,1)
    /*
      let arrayy = [...this.state.array]
      let removed = arrayy.splice(deger,1);
      this.setState({
        array:arrayy,
      })
    */

    add(){
      const deger = document.getElementById('deger').value;
      const todosarray = this.state.todos;
      todosarray.push(deger)
      this.setState({
        todos:todosarray,
      })
    }

    remove(num){
      let arrayy = [...this.state.todos]
      arrayy.splice(num,1)
      this.setState({
        array:arrayy,
      })
    }

    render() {
      const data = this.state.todos;
      const listItems = data.map((result,i) => <li key={i} onClick={this.remove(i)}>{result }</li>);
      return (
        <div >
          <input id="deger"></input>
          <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
          <div id="items">
            {listItems}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
onClick={this.remove(i)}
```

By this:

```
onClick={() => this.remove(i)}
```

Explanation: while rendering, React evaluates `this.remove(i)`, which changes the state or the props, thus triggering another render, and looping to re-evaluate `this.remove(i)`; creating a (hidden) infinite loop. `() => this.remove(i)` is a function so the state or the props do not change. Also, it's probably what you wanted to code anyway ;)

Comment: Maybe because you're [using index as a key](https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c)